# How can I store an image in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I want to store an image in a database , but I don't know how , I have tried this but it shows me errors of type , could someone help me to deal with this , I ve create an image with blob type in database here s my code :

```
 var bytes;
  var encoded1;
Future pickImage() async {
    tempStore = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    bytes = await tempStore.readAsBytes();
    encoded1 = base64.decode(bytes);

    print(tempStore);
    //var tempStore = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      pickedImage = tempStore;
      isImageLoaded = true;
    });
  }
```

and this is where I'm trying to insert the image in a database

```
final dao = Provider.of<ClientDao>(context);
                              final client = Client(
                                typeClientid: idTypeClient,
                                nom: prenomController.text,
                                prenom: nameController.text,
                                ddn: ddnController.text,
                                ville: adresseController.text,
                                ncd: numeroController.text,
                                imageDevant: encoded1,

                              );
                              dao.insertClient(client);
```

Comment: Why don't you store the image in the filesystem, and refer to it from the database?

Comment: @bereal is it doable in an android app ? I ve been thinking to store just the path of the image

Comment: Sure it is: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode your bytes before store not decode (base64.encode)

Comment: should I change the type of an Image to String ?@mohghaderi

Comment: Yes Base64 is string

Comment: I don't know if you had the same issue , when I add this , it creates errors with the id , but when I delete the image from the database everything works fine

Comment: I can't help without knowing what the db configuration or the error is

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498645/adding-attribute-image-in-a-database-creates-some-errors I post it as a question

Answer (score 0):

The best way to store image is using blob type, base64 is better for transmission.